# Wiremock disable response when matching fails

Tags: response, wiremock, disable

I am using Wiremock Standalone 2.21 and am using query parameters matching at requests. I want Wiremock to **not** to respond (or maybe customize the response if possible) when the matching fails. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: In the provided example you refer to `"Some Regex"` when you try without the regex, does the rule trigger? Starting with a working examples and making small alterations is generally the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using [Stub Priority](http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/#stub-priority) in WireMock.

In the below example there are two rules. One Specific and one Generic Catch All. Both rules will match your input, but through setting the right priority you can make sure the application follows your desired sequence of matching. In this case if the URL is `/api/specific-resource` then the first rule will map. If the url is `/api/some-other` then the second rule will apply.

the Specific Rule:

```
{
    "priority": 1,
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/api/specific-resource"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200
    }
}
```

The Generic Rule:

```
{
    "priority": 10,
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "urlPattern": "/api/*"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and am becoming the "Request was not matched" message instead of the errorresponse i want to see. I am matching the sent query parameter to a regex like so:         `"request": {
   "method": "POST",
   "urlPattern":"/test.*",
   "queryParameters" : {
    "test" : {
     "matches" : "<someRegex>"
    }
   }`

Comment: Please add new information (i.e. the example) to your question. The Answer comment section is for asking for clarifications or alterations in the provided answer. Often one refers to updates to the question when commenting.